# Jenkins - Making a Build Fail if Javadoc is Missing

Tags: java, jenkins, javadoc, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Jenkins for continuous source integration, and I can't figure out how to make a build fail if there are missing javadoc tags or comments. What do I need to do to make this happen?

Comment: You probably need to use something like `Checkstyle` with your custom code style rules setup -- then run `Checkstyle` before you try to compile, and bail out if `Checkstyle` fails. http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Let the javadocs be generated and fail on warnings? But isn't CI the wrong place for this? Seems more like a sonarqube task...

Comment: @Hannes it seems he is more after if a javadoc comment is not present for a method or something -- javadoc won't fail, it just won't generate anything for that method. -- If that is the case, then I believe `Checkstyle` is really the only way to go (with custom rules setup to check for javadoc comments on every method and fail if one is missing).

Comment: That's not even a class C bug. CI is definitely the wrong place for it.

Comment: @Hannes agreed. However I've seen more than once a Checkstyle built into an Ant script so that the codebase gets checked prior to every compile... not perfect, but it's something... (he could be using this to check code style quality of contributions or something...)

Answer (score 0):

You need [**Jenkins Text Finder**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin) plugin. It will allow you to search the build log, or any other set of files under workspace for a Regular Expression, and then set the build result accordingly