# How do I fail a build in Jenkins if a particular stage is not added?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a stage which checks whether any hardcoded credentials aren't going into the build.

This is done using a `custom jenkins library`.

Now, there are many pipelines in which I need to add, so I figured out two solutions :

1. Make a python script and manually figure out the text pattern in each/most of these `Jenkinsfile`s where I can add my stage.
2. Let Jenkins do the work of checking whether the stage exists and if not fail the build, so that the developer could herself/himself add the stage.

Now, 2nd is the one I would like to go with as it's quite scalable ( so to say ) and I don't have to go with the unreliableness of pattern searching to add the stage using python and moreover I already have tried out the 1st one.

This question is similar to this : [jenkins-making-a-build-fail-if-javadoc-is-missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456256/jenkins-making-a-build-fail-if-javadoc-is-missing)

In the above question, the solution seeker wishes to fail the build based on `javadoc` string.

The solution as suggested is a plugin, but I don't want to increase the complexity to this solution because for this I will have to learn plugin development for Jenkins and seeing that it's in JAVA, it will take even more time ( I am fluent in Python ).

I have worked, rather struggled with groovy to make a Jenkin libs, but I am ready to walk that path, if need be.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking if you could introduce some kind of global variable in your flow which will store all the env.STAGE_NAME at the beginning of each stage (need just one-liner on every stage). At the end of the flow, you validate all the stage names from the list and see if you are missing anything.